# How can header cells in Excel be "pinned" or "frozen"?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can you "pin" or "freeze" cells in the top row and/or leftmost column of an MS Excel sheet, so that they always remain visible regardless of scrolling?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If this is Excel 2007, you are looking for "Freeze Pane" under the View tab. If you want to know how to use it, open Excel help and look for freeze. The first result should be a detailed explanation on how to use the feature.

Comment: Ah, _that's_ what it's called. Thanks. There's a short explanation with screenshots [here](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excel101/ss/freeze_pane_4.htm); in more recent versions of Excel, there's a Freeze Panes button under the View segment of the ribbon.

Comment: And the Excel 2007 version of that tutorial is [here](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/exceltools/ss/81027freezepane.htm).

Comment: This works for Excel 2013 too.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this, is there's a bar in the upper right corner that you can drag down for a horizontal split. I don't have a copy of Excel so I can't show you the effect, but here's the little bar:
[image]

There's also a little bar on the bottom of the screen that you can drag for a vertical split.

Comment: This doesn't actually freeze the header cells; instead, it splits the window so you get two semi-independent views of it. Both functions can be useful, but for best results, don't confuse them.

Comment: @Martha -- Agreed, but I find having to line everything up and hunting for a menu much more tedious than just grabbing the handle and sliding it around. I pointed it out because it's a feature of Excel that most people don't know about. I gave him the option.

Answer (score 1):

Here's mate for bahamat's answer: there's a corresponding vertical bar at the bottom right corner of the screen that works the same way for isolating columns.

[image: screenshot of vertical bar near where the scrollbars meet]

A bar can also appear to the left of the horizontal scrollbar as well, but this one doesn't do splitting. Instead, it is used for resizing the horizontal scrollbar:

[image: screenshot of vertical bar to the left of the horizontal scrollbar]